# Symfony2 installing FOSUserBundle issue

Tags: symfony, debian, bundle, fosuserbundle, composer-php

I want to install FOSUserBundle in symfony2 but when I tell the composer to download the bundle nothing happens.

Here is the composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
},
```

and when I try to run the good command line :

```
xavier@Debian: su php composer.phar update --prefer-dist friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
xavier@Debian:
```

I have already tried without `--prefer-dist`, doesn't change anything.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved ! I had to add this : `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar` at the end of my php.ini if it could help someone.